# How to get the count of distinct values in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

Dictionary is below

```
todos = [{'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'A', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'B ', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'C', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'A', 'completed': True},
     {'userId': 2, 'id': 1,'title': 'B', 'completed': False}]
```

Code is below to print the values

```
for i in todos:
    print((i['userId']))
for i in todos:
    print((i['title']))
for i in todos:
    print((i['completed']))
```

Expected out is

```
{"userid" : 2, "title":3, "completed" : 2}
```

I just need the distinct count of values

- `userid` there are only 2 because `1` and `2` values are present
- `title` is 3 as values are `A`, `B` ,`C`
- `completed` is 2 as values are `True` and `False`

Comment: Should 'B ' be 'B' - remove extra blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following without importing pandas:

```
todos = [{'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'A', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'B ', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'C', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'A', 'completed': True},
     {'userId': 2, 'id': 1,'title': 'B', 'completed': False}]
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda:[])
for todo in todos:
    for k,v in todo.items():
        d[k].append(v)
d = {k:len(set(v)) for k,v in d.items()}
print(d)
```

output:

```
{'userId': 2, 'id': 2, 'title': 4, 'completed': 2}
```

**EXPLAINATION:**
first you create a defaultdict the initializes default values when not existed `d = defaultdict(lambda:[])`

create a dict of lists instead of dict of lists

```
for todo in todos:
    for k,v in todo.items():
        d[k].append(v)
```

then you extract the uniquevalues with set and measure the length `{k:len(set(v)) for k,v in d.items()}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and length of the [set](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) like so:

```
cnt = {}
for todos_key in todos[0].keys():
    cnt[todos_key] = len(set([item[todos_key] for item in todos]))
print(cnt)
# {'userId': 2, 'id': 2, 'title': 4, 'completed': 2}
```

Comment: you can also directly use set comprehension
`len({x['userId'] for x in todos})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` to do so.

Just create a data-frame from the `todos` dictionary and then using the [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) method.

```
import pandas as pd
todos = [{'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'A', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'B ', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'C', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'A', 'completed': True},
     {'userId': 2, 'id': 1,'title': 'B', 'completed': False}]
df = pd.DataFrame(todos)
df['userId'].nunique()
df['title'].nunique()
df['completed'].nunique()
```

Notice that the second dicionay title is `B`  and not `B` so you might need to handle it.